# Python print full text file

Tags: python, replace, text-files

I want to replace the word "example" on textfile2.txt with a list of words from textfile1.txt until the list runs out or all the "example" have all been replaced then I want to display the whole finished text.

How would I do this?

textfile1.txt

```
user1
user2
```

textfile2.txt

```
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow

URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
```

Current code:

```
with open('textfile1.txt') as f1, open('textfile2.txt') as f2:
    for l, r in zip(f1, f2):
        print(r[:r.find('/example') + 1] + l)
```

Results it gives me:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/user1

user2
```

Goal:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/user1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow

URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/user2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
```

Comment: Zip will terminate as soon as one list is exhausted.  So, 2 lines in 1 file and 5 lines in 2nd file means 2 passes.  Only 1 of which replaces as you want. 2nd doesn't find *example* so returns 2nd line of f1.

Answer (score 3):

here is the my solution:

```
with open('t1.txt') as f1, open('t2.txt') as f2:
    url_info = f2.read().split('\n\n')
    users = f1.read().split('\n')
    zipped_list = zip(users, url_info)
    for item in zipped_list:
        print item[1].replace('example', item[0])+"\n"
```

**updated:**
this need import itertools

```
import itertools
with open('t1.txt') as f1, open('t2.txt') as f2:
    url_info = f2.read().split('\n\n')
    users = [u for u in f1.read().split('\n') if u]
    zipped_list = list(itertools.izip(url_info, itertools.cycle(users)))    
    for item in zipped_list:        
        print item[0].replace('example', item[1])+"\n"
```

output:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/user1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow

URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/user2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow

URL GOTO=https://www.url.com/user1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
```

Comment: This won't work correctly if the number of occurences of 'example' in textfile2 is greater than the number of words in textfile1. 

The question says  I want to replace the word "example" on textfile2.txt with a list of words from textfile1.txt **until the list runs out** or all the "example" have all been replaced then I want to display the whole finished text.